# Save text as curves with ggplot ggsave

Tags: r, pdf-generation

The following code will create a plot in a `PDF` file

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=hp))+
  geom_point() +
ggsave(filename="test1.pdf")
```

There are only very few characters, but they are fragile as long they are not curves.
I want to conserve the appeareance.

```
$ pdffonts test1.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            no  no  no      10  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            no  no  no      11  0
```

How can I convert the text and symbols to curves?

```
running R 2.15 on debian squeeze
```

[picture explaining what text-to-curves](http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/text-vs-curves.jpg) means

Comment: Are you asking how to embed fonts?  (See `?embedFonts` ...) Can you give a little more detail about what "fragile" means in this context?

Comment: It sounds like you can use Ghostscript to do this: try out various answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/how-to-convert-text-in-a-pdf-file-from-fonts-text-to-outlines , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23407/how-can-i-convert-text-to-paths-with-pdflatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/how-to-convert-text-in-a-pdf-file-from-fonts-text-to-outlines : I called this script `pdfsquash`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "x$1" = "x" -o "x$2" = "x" ]; then
    echo Usage: `basename "$0"` "<input.pdf>" "<output.pdf>" >&2
    exit 1
fi
gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q \
   -dbatch -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET "$1" -c quit | ps2pdf - "$2"
```

I ran your code, then (outside of R, although you could also use `system()`):

```
pdfsquash test1.pdf test1S.pdf
```

The original:

```
pdffonts test1.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            no  no  no      10  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            no  no  no      11  0
```

New:

```
pdffonts test1S.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
```